# Can I place my Skype notifications on my secondary monitor?

Tags: skype, notifications, multiple-monitors

I've just upgraded my Skype to version 5.

I get the new notifications in the top right of my primary monitor. My main Skype window is always on my secondary monitor.

I had a look at the options...

[image: Skype Notifications Preferences]

...but nothing seems to let me place it on my secondary monitor.

Is there a way to do this somehow? Any *advanced options* hidden somewhere?

Comment: Looks like you can do this - at least with Skype for Business on Windows. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sfb-mso_win10/skype-for-business-alerts-multiple-monitors-choose/9f27f8a3-985c-4f70-9ef1-8c05852093c6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible to customize notifications to appear on a monitor of your choice, but this [thread](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=106861) should give you some insights on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick read of that Skype thread, it doesn't look too hopeful.  If that doesn't pan out, look at [SkypeToGrowl and Growl For Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/apps.aspx).  Chances are GFW can put its notifications where ever you want them, with the advantage that all your notifications will go to one location and share it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this is what I found when looking for the answer:
Skype for Business, Settings, Alerts, Change your monitor and position:

[image: image of setting options]